# Is it possible to add files to Amazon S3 buckets using web URL as source?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to load one of my S3 buckets.

File i am trying to load is huge tarball on the web, I don't want to download file on my disk and then again start uploading it to S3 bucket.

is there any way that I can directly specify this URL and it get added to S3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to "put" to S3, and it does not "get".